# Authorship of Rashi's Bible commentary

Tags: tanach, rashi, provenance, authorship

Besides for the commentary on Divrei Hayamim (which as noted [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/betmikra/betmikra109.pdf) was not written by Rashi), is the authorship of any of the commentaries to the Bible attributed to Rashi disputed?

Comment: Mayer Gruber's introduction to "Rashi on Psalms" has a pretty good overview of the various opinions, and whether or not we should question his authorship on Psalms, the last sections of Job, and Ezra-Nehemiah

Comment: @MoriDowidhYa3aqov Just saw it. Haven't had a chance to read it yet. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 10):

Chida in [Shem Hagedolim](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/shemhagdolim/shemhagdolim10.pdf) (page 7 of the file) quotes Seder Hadoros, who says that the commentary on Iyov isn't from Rashi. On that same page he also quotes someone who claims that none of the commentary on Neviim is from Rashi, although he disagrees with that.

Comment: See the article by Moshe Sokolow, "Establishing the Text of Rashi's Commentary on the Book of Job," PAAJR 48 (1948). He doesn't think this claim should be taken seriously (and the Chida himself didn't seem so sure to me)

Comment: @mevaqesh I don't carry around a frumometer to measure anyone's frumkeit, but I can tell you that Gruber does not usually wear a yarmulke but Moshe Sokolow does and lives in a frum community